# Android mata um processo do tcpdump

Tags: android

Eu tenho uma app em Java que roda em Android. Esse app inicia um o Tcpdump `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c tcpdump -s 0 -v -w /sdcard/capture.pcap`. Isso funciona e gera o arquivo, a capturar os pacotes passantes na rede 3G do device.

Ocorre que, abruptamente, o processo do tcpdump é eliminado (eu fiquei monitorando a lista de processos ativos) depois de um tempo.

Alguém teria ideia por que isso acontece? E alguma possível solução?

Comment: O código tá cortado, ou está faltando um `")`, não sei bem, posta ele como esta, não sei se tem mais coisas pra podermos reproduzir o problema

Comment: Ele mata só o processo do tcpdump? ou o teu app também?

Comment: Opa, desculpe-me. A falta do ") foi só problema na hora de copiar e colar aqui. É assim: process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c tcpdump -s 0 -v -w /sdcard/experimentos/capture_"+name+".pcap");, onde nome é uma string recebida como argumento. O Tcpdump incia perfeitamente, mas posteriormente é eliminado aleiamente ao meu app (deve ser o próprio OS que o elimina). Apenas o Tcpdump é morto, meu app continua funcionando perfeitamente.